# How do I add and animate infinite number of objects coming from the bottom of the screen in random order in gradually increasing speeds?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have 3 different sprites. I want to continuously animate these three different sprites entering from the bottom of the screen, going up increasing velocities as the number of objects coming in increases. Also, the three should come in random order.

So, I tried the following code to get any of the three sprites to come in any random order but it didn't work as expected:

int randomNumber;

```
for (int i = 1; i<500; i++) {
    randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(3);
    NSLog(@"Value of random Number %d" ,randomNumber);

if (randomNumber == 0) {
        [self addRedBall];
        SKAction *moveBall = [SKAction moveToY:CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) duration:5];

    dispatch_queue_t actionDispatchRed;

    actionDispatchRed = dispatch_queue_create("com.redball.dispatch", NULL);

    dispatch_async(actionDispatchRed, ^ {   [redBall runAction:moveBall];   });
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];   //Time interval to wait before the next ball comes in.

    }

else if (randomNumber == 1) {
        [self addBlueBall];

        dispatch_queue_t actionDispatchBlue;

        SKAction *moveBall = [SKAction moveToY:CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) duration:5];
        actionDispatchBlue = dispatch_queue_create("com.blueball.dispatch", NULL);

        dispatch_async(actionDispatchBlue, ^{  [blueBall runAction:moveBall];  });
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];


    }
else if (randomNumber == 2) {
        [self addGreenBall];
        SKAction *moveBall = [SKAction moveToY:CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) duration:5
                              ];
        dispatch_queue_t actionDispatchGreen;
        actionDispatchGreen = dispatch_queue_create("com.greenball.dispatch", NULL);

        dispatch_async(actionDispatchGreen,
                       ^ {  [greenBall runAction:moveBall]; } );

    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];

    }


}
```

When I use the [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2]; , the program does not go any further than the starting screen.

When I try to run the program without the sleepForTimeInterval, a huge number of sprites come in and overlap each other resulting in only one visible sprite.

Please help.

Comment: And while I'm wishing, I'd like a pony. :)

Comment: @matt - You always struck me as a Clydesdale kinda guy.

Comment: Now that you have told us what you want to do, please update your question with some relevant code showing what you have tried. Explain what issues you are having with the code.

Comment: Okay, I have updated the question. Please look into this and help. Sorry for the previous incovienience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend using `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];`

Instead trying using `[self performSelector:@selector(addBall) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];`

```
-(void)addBall
{
    self.addedBall++;
    if (self.addedBall > 500)
    {
        return;
    }

    randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(3);

    if (randomNumber == 0) {
        [self addRedBall];
        SKAction *moveBall = [SKAction moveToY:CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) duration:5];

        dispatch_queue_t actionDispatchRed;

        actionDispatchRed = dispatch_queue_create("com.redball.dispatch", NULL);

        dispatch_async(actionDispatchRed, ^ {   [redBall runAction:moveBall];   });

        [self performSelector:@selector(addBall) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
    }
    //other else if stuff

}
```

Also I am unsure why you are running your SKActions in a dispatch_queue and is likely not needed.

I hope that helps.

Comment: What is "addedBall" in the if statement and the increment? 
And should I replace my code that I have in the question with yours and call the addBall in didMoveToView?
Sorry if this is too dumb, I am a noob

Comment: In your original code you have a for loop that is executed 500 times. The addBall is just an NSInteger that you can increment. I put it in there as a check to stop calling addball. You don't really need it if you don't care how many times you call addball at this point. Yes replace your code with that and call it once in didMoveToView. We were all new once and I know sometimes it can be tough to communicate online. Just make sure you replace the other NSThread stuff in your other two else ifs.

Comment: I did! It is animating just as I wanted it to! Thanks a million! One more thing though, I am not able to react to touches on the balls now. Is it because the ball is executing an action and Cannot respond while it is animating?

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark this as answered. Actions will not prevent touch to my knowledge. You will want to make sure that when you create the SKSpriteNode that you set userInteractionEnabled to YES. With that being said I would create a new question for that issue with a code example of how you create the sprite and how you check if it is responding to touch.

Comment: I do have my userInteractionEnabled to YES. I wrote the code to get a log message when some sprite on the screen was touched, I do get a log message every time but How do I get to know what sprite was touched and in turn make that particular sprite run some action? Sorry, I cannot add a new question right now cause my question limit has been reached! Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Hey, it works perfectly fine when I run it as an individual project, but when I compile it with several scenes at a time, it just adds one of the balls to the screen and thats it. Can you help?

Comment: @RohanKalantri I see your other question and you will need to post the entire method there and then maybe we can help.

Comment: Okay, I have added the entire method to the other question.